# A graph that Prints all paths from a given source to a destination in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

[Print all paths from a given source to a destination in c, java and python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/)

I'm a beginner in PHP, and I tried to code in PHP the code in this link, but my code doesn't give output nor error.
I don't know what is wrong in my PHP code.

This is my code:

```
<?php
class Graph{
    private $v;
    private $adjList;
    public function __construct($vertices){
        $this->v=$vertices;

        $this->initAdjList();
    }

    //@suppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private function initAdjList(){
        $this->adjList = array($this->v);
        for($i=0; $i<$this->v;$i++){
            $this->adjList[$i]=array();
        }
    }

    public function addEdge($u, $v){
        array_push($this->adjList[$u],$v);
    }

    public function printAllPaths($s, $d){
        $isVisted=array();
        $isVisted=array_fill(0,$this->v,false);
        $pathList=array();
        array_push($pathList,$s);
        $this->printAllPathsUtil($s, $d, $isVisted,$pathList);
    }

    private function printAllPathsUtil($u,$d,$isVisted,$localPathList){
        $isVisted[intval($u)]=true;

        if(intval($u)==intval($d)){
           // echo $localPathList;
            print_r($localPathList);
        }

        foreach ($this->adjList as $i){
            if(!$isVisted[intval($i)]){
                array_push($localPathList,$i);
                $this->printAllPathsUtil($i, $d, $isVisted, $localPathList);
                array_splice($localPathList,intval($i),1);
            }
        }
        $isVisted[intval($u)]=false;
    }
}

$g=new Graph(5);
$g->addEdge(0,1);
$g->addEdge(0,2);
$g->addEdge(0,3);
$g->addEdge(2,0);
$g->addEdge(2,1);
$g->addEdge(1,3);
$g->addEdge(3,1);
$g->addEdge(3,2);
$g->addEdge(4,3);
$g->addEdge(3,4);
$s=0;
$d=4;
$g->printAllPaths($s,$d);
?>
```

Expected output :
    0 3 4
    0 1 3 4
    0 2 1 3 4

Comment: Have you made any attempt to debug it? Run it under xdebug?  Added error logging (or even just echo statements at key points)?  Enabled error_reporting and display_errors?

Comment: @GordonM Can you assume best intentions, please? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311737/lets-hold-language-in-comments-to-the-same-standard-as-posts

Comment: @GordonM I'm sorry for being late in my reply. According to your advice to debug the code, i found out the i forgot the index of the adjList array in the foreach statement which should look like ' $this->adjList[$u] '.
now i'm getting an output but it isn't a correct one.